# Read local file from project directory | Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile | KMM

Tags: android, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to read `JSON` file which is saved in my project locally and want to fetch and read using `Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile`, so I can share with Android and iOS

Following approch I'm doing:

In commonMain :

```
package com.example.readJSON.shared

import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class DataRequest(
    val dataRegimenRequest: List<DataRegimenRequest>?
)

expect class FileResource(location: String){
    val json: String?
}
```

In androidMain :

```
package com.example.readJSON.shared

actual class FileResource actual constructor(location: String) {
    actual val json: String? = this::class.java.classLoader!!.getResource(location)?.readText()
}
```

In iosMain :

```
package com.example.readJSON.shared

actual class FileResource actual constructor(location: String) {
    actual val json: String? = null //TODO: write a code to read from local file
}
```

Can someone will help me, how can I fetch my local `JSON` file for iOS?

For Android, I am able to read local `JSON` file.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need to write some gradle to copy the file to your iOS app source, then load it by reading iOS resource files from the Bundle. It's a little hard to follow, but we push in a Swift function to handle that [here](https://github.com/touchlab/DroidconKotlin/blob/master/iosApp/iosApp/app/AppDelegate.swift#L63). You could write that code in iOS Kotlin as well.

You *might* be able to add the file to Xcode directly without needing to copy it in Gradle. From Xcode, right-click your source folder and select "Add Files to ___", then point it at the file. If all of your source is in a single repo, you should be able to point at that file with a relative path from Xcode, and load it at runtime.

For Android, you'd *probably* want to put that file in `assets` rather than load it with the class loader, but that's a different discussion.

Answer (score 0):

for ios

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class)
actual fun loadJsonFile(fileName: String, androidContext: Any?): String? {
val path =
    NSBundle.mainBundle.pathForResource("compose-resources/json/$fileName", ofType = "json")
        ?: "no"
return NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile(path, encoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding, error = null)
    ?: run {
        error("Couldn't load resource: $fileName. Error: ")
    }
}
```

where file is in "resources/json/" folder, name if file is "1.json" must "1"